# Nesting a Loop inside of a Parallel Foreach Loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

Let's say for this example, I want to divide a lot of files a number of different ways.

```
DIVIDERS = c(2,3,5,10)
```

I have a list of files, and Im planning to do operations on each file, using each divider.  I want to do this in parallel.

I have:

```
foreach(x = DIVIDERS) %dopar% {
     for( y in listOfFiles ) {
           print( paste( x,  y, sep = "" ) )
```

This is just preliminary to make sure that I am indeed getting every "X" divider with every "Y" file.  However, they all print out null. I imagine this is an issue with nesting loops in parallel.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to export `listOfFiles` to each of the subthreads:

```
foreach(x = DIVIDERS, .export=) %dopar% {
     for( y in listOfFiles ) {
           print( paste( x,  y, sep = "" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of nesting is fine; you're just not returning the results properly. The foreach loop is returning NULLs because the inner `for` loop returns an invisible NULL.

Try this instead:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

DIVIDERS <- c(2,3,5,10)
listOfFiles <- c('file1', 'file2', 'file3')

newlist <-
  foreach(x=DIVIDERS, .combine='c') %dopar% {
    sublist <- vector('list', length(listOfFiles))
    for(i in seq_along(listOfFiles)) {
      y <- listOfFiles[[i]]
      sublist[[i]] <- paste(x,  y, sep = "")
    }
    sublist
  }
```

Note that this uses `.combine='c'` so that we get a list of strings, rather than a list of lists of strings.

Although there is no problem nesting a `for` loop inside a `foreach` loop, I would use `lapply` in this case:

```
newlist <-
  foreach(x=DIVIDERS, .combine='c') %dopar% {
    lapply(listOfFiles, function(y) paste(x, y, sep=""))
  }
```